# How can I get at the matches when using preg_replace in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-replace

I am trying to grab the capital letters of a couple of words and wrap them in span tags. I am using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for extract and wrapping purposes, but it's not outputting anything.

```
preg_replace("/[A-Z]/", "<span class=\"initial\">$1</span>", $str)
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to put the pattern in parentheses `/([A-Z])/`, like this:

```
preg_replace("/([A-Z])/", "<span class=\"initial\">$1</span>", $str)
```

Comment: @Gumbo: Answering your own questions is perfectly fine, even encouraged, as long as the question isn't a duplicate of another one on the site.

Comment: The `$1` bit in the replacement string is what I was needing. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

`\0` will also match the entire matched expression without doing an explicit capture using parenthesis.

```
preg_replace("/[A-Z]/", "<span class=\"initial\">\\0</span>", $str)
```

As always, you can go to [php.net/preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) or php.net/<whatever search term> to search the documentation quickly. Quoth the documentation:

> \0 or $0 refers to the text matched by the whole pattern.

Answer (score 8):

From the [preg_replace documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) on php.net:

> *replacement*  may contain references of
>   the form \n or (since PHP 4.0.4) $n,
>   with the latter form being the
>   preferred one. Every such reference
>   will be replaced by the text captured
>   by the n'th parenthesized pattern.

See Flubba's example.

Answer (score 5):

Use parentheses around your desired capture.

Comment: A capture group is unnecessary when the full string match is desired.