# What is $0 on PHP PCRE functions

Tags: php, preg-replace, pcre

I read a documentation of `preg_filter` function it is look as follows. This is [from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php) site.

```
$subject = array('1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'A', 'B', '4'); 
$pattern = array('/\d/', '/[a-z]/', '/[1a]/'); 
$replace = array('A:$0', 'B:$0', 'C:$0'); 

print_r(preg_filter($pattern, $replace, $subject));
```

Here in the array of $replace some variables available like this - `$0`
When I try this it is returning the value was available before replace. 
Is it a common variable on PHP or is it only available for PCRE functions? And i seen `$1`, `$2`, `$3` ... also in some articles.

Normally we can't have variables starting with numbers.

So can any one explain about this function and variable?

Comment: 'A:$0' is between single quotes, it won't be interpreted as a variable anyway.

Comment: Relevant: [How can I get at the matches when using preg_replace in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1746/2943403)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$0` represents the entire part of the string that matches the pattern. `$1` and so on represent the subpatterns.

Comment: can you please give me a sample for sub pattern to see $1 value.

Comment: Example: `preg_match("/abc(def)ghi/","012abcdefghi345",$m); var_dump($m));`. The indices of the `$m` array can be used in replacements as `$0` and `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual page for `preg_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php):

> preg_filter() is identical to preg_replace() except it only returns the (possibly transformed) subjects where there was a match. For details about how this function works, read the preg_replace() documentation.

From the [manual page for `preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> $0 refers to the text matched by the whole pattern.

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP manual on `preg_replace` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php:

> Every such reference will be replaced by the text captured by the n'th
>   parenthesized pattern. n can be from 0 to 99, and **\0** or **$0** refers to
>   the text matched by the whole pattern.