# append using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I want to rename duplicate entries in PHP doc blocks:

```
 * @property \App\Models\Invitation[] $invitations
 * @property \App\Models\Invitation[] $invitations
```

should become

```
 * @property \App\Models\Invitation[] $invitations
 * @property \App\Models\Invitation[] $invitations2
```

I already have code that identifies duplicates and then I iterate over the property names that I want to append the number to:

```
preg_replace('/\@property [^ ]* \$' . $property . '/', ..., $docBlock)
```

I am just struggeling to find a way to use the text that if finds with the regex in the replacement statement:

```
preg_replace('/\@property [^ ]* \$' . $property . '/', MATCHED_TEXT.$i , $docBlock
```

Comment: Why preg_replace?

Comment: I am also open to a preg_match solution

Comment: Replace `MATCHED_TEXT` to `'$0'`, but why can't you simply use: `$text .= $i` or `$text = $text.$i`?

Comment: @Mateus because the matched text can be anywhere inside a longer text block

Comment: @Mateus btw your $0 suggestion did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to do is get everything caught by the regex (`MATCHED_TEXT`) in this piece of code:

```
preg_replace('/\@property [^ ]* \$' . $property . '/', MATCHED_TEXT.$i , $docBlock)
```

To get the entire match, you can use `"$0"` in the replacement area.

#### Final code

```
preg_replace('/\@property [^ ]* \$' . $property . '/', '$0'.$i , $docBlock)
```

> **$0** represents the entire part of the string that matches the pattern. **$1** and so on represent the subpatterns.
>
> Reference: [Niet the Dark Absol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9861651/7225971)

Answer (score 1):

**`preg_replace_callback`** solution:

```
$docBlock = '
* @property \App\Models\Invitation[] $invitations
* @property \App\Models\Invitation[] $invitations
* @property \App\Models\Invitation[] $invitations';

$property = 'invitations';
$c = 0;  // count
$result = preg_replace_callback('/(\@property \S* \$)('. $property .')/', function ($m) use(&$c){
    return $m[1] . $m[2] . (++$c == 1? '' : $c);
}, $docBlock);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
* @property \App\Models\Invitation[] $invitations
* @property \App\Models\Invitation[] $invitations2
* @property \App\Models\Invitation[] $invitations3
```

Comment: Faster/Simpler with no capture groups, just `\K`.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f699de23bde9e946c5d7ecf1525830bac72dea37

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version without regex.
I use a temp array with the key name the same as string line and value is the "number".
Then it's just a matter of looping and adding the number to the line.

```
$str = '@property \App\Models\Invitation[] $invitations
@property \App\Models\Invitation[] $invitations
@blogpost
@blogpost
@blogpost
@blogpost';

$arr = explode("\n", $str);

$temp = array();
Foreach($arr as &$item){
    If(isset($temp[$item])){
        $key = $item;
        $item .= $temp[$item];
        $temp[$key] = $temp[$key]+1;
    }Else{
        $temp[$item] = 2;
    }
}
Echo implode("\n",$arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/i1bCv