# "\0" in PCRE RegEx in PHP

Tags: php, regex, pcre

```
 <?php
  $pattern = "/http:\\/\\/(([A-Za-z0-9.\-])*)/";
  $text = "http://www.google.com";
  $text = preg_replace($pattern,"<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>",$text);
  echo $text;
 ?>
```

The code above gets the URL from a string variable and adds an HTML tag           for a link. So "`http://www.google.com`" becomes "`<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`". 
My question is how "\0" is something like placeholder for the value of the parameter "$text" in the "preg_repace" function, after it means NULL or 0x0?

Comment: ``"\\0"`` ([=``'\0'``](https://ideone.com/5N8Ior)) is a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to the whole match.

Comment: There is an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31874/3832970).

Comment: Use single quotes and change your delimiter, then you won't need as much escaping. `'~http://(([A-Za-z0-9.\-])*)~'`.